# What is the Order-Conferring Trade Pattern?

Tags: exalted

I recently heard about Exalted's "Order-Conferring Trade Pattern" - a concept related to solidifying Creation through commerce. However, I can't seem to find a clear source to where that idea was described and what it is exactly - which book describes the Pattern and how does it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's from the book Masters of Jade (2e).

Essentially, the great sages of the First Age intentionally set up a web of commerce that would function as a ward against Wyld - by circulating jade, iron, and silver, and by promoting constant interaction, it would tie all the furthest bits of the world together, and prevent any from breaking off due to isolation and floating away into the madness of the Wyld.

Comment: The idea of the Order Conferring Trade Pattern is mentioned prior to that book, as far as I remember it is referred to in the Dreams of the First Age books and the Wyld supplement.
It links in with the description of Wyld Shaping Technique: "anything created with this Charm is more ephemeral than those native to Creation, and may fade if they do not interact with the rest of Creation's reality."